# how to build Generic CRUD Controller using Spring Proxy & BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, proxy

I'm planning to build a generic infrastructure for MVC `CrudController` and Generic `CrudService` using interface Proxies and custom annotation processing, because i have multiple endpoints in my project with the same CRUD pattern.

the bottom line is - defining interfaces of `CrudController` and `CrudServices` and create a `ProxyBean` for my interfaces and process cutsom annotation, i want to achieve the same pattern as **spring data repositires** where you need to define you repository interface **only**,
for example:

```
interface CrudController<T>{
  //crud method...
}

interface CrudService<T>{
  //crud method...
}

class GenericCrudControllerImpl<T>{
private CrudService<T> service;
//crud methods implementation and call service crud methods
}
```

the usage of this pattern would be like the following:

```
@CrudRestController(service=PersonCrudService.class) //PersonCrudService implements CrudService 
class CrudPersonController implements CrudController<Person>{}
```

i know i should use Spring's `FactoryBean<T>` interfaces along with `BeanPostProcessor`, but the problem i don't know how to read the generic parameter of my CrudController, e.g. Person to be able to instansiate my generic implementations with the generic paramters, e.g. Person.

i need assistance how to use the ProxyBean pattern and BeanPostProcessor the right way to acheive the implementation above, i couldn't find any useful examples on the web.

Comment: Have a look at Spring Data REST [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond i'm looking to make my own implementation. i don't use spring repository (i can't for some reason). but i want to acheive the same effect/IMPL

Comment: In that case my suggestion would be have a look at the implementation for  spring data and cherry pick the features which you need. (*although this is like re-inventing the wheel*)

Comment: i understand what you mean, but the thing is my DB is not standrd DB, i use SaaS service for persistancy, so its not a standard DB, and i can't use any of the default repostirioes

Comment: Maybe Netflix Feign? http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign